spark sql write.parquet overwrite issue
I am using spark scala jar application on Databricks runtime version is 13.3 LTS, scala version 2.12, spark 3.4.1 and in my application I have a line like below
incomingDF.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
  .partitionBy("partition_date")
  .parquet(tablePath)

This line of code couldn't achieve it's purpose while running as jar file it didn't throw an error and finises as successfullt. It couldn't update the target tablePath.
But whenever I ran exactly same code on above inside datarbricks notebook. It runs successfully and update the tablePath. I can not find the solution. Can you please help me on that one?

how are you defining tablePath? Databricks abstract lots of features that you must create if you're running a local application. Assuming you're using mounting points try /dbfs:/..your path or /dbfs/...your path

Hi @LeonardoPedroso it's start with abfss://red-dev...

Do you see any exceptions when used inside the error handler routine? I see you are using the Absolute path. I hope the necessary permissions are defined.

After talking with Databricks support I learned that there is a parameter called. spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode which have two parameter dynamic and static. If you set dynamic it will just update the partition which have new data in your new dataframe. But if you set static it will update the whole folder inside folder path.
